# Pandas - group by id and drop duplicate with threshold

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, duplicates, threshold

I have the following data:

```
userid itemid
  1       1
  1       1
  1       3
  1       4
  2       1
  2       2
  2       3
```

I want to drop userIDs who has viewed the same itemID more than or equal to twice. 
For example, userid=1 has viewed itemid=1 twice, and thus I want to drop the entire record of userid=1. However, since userid=2 hasn't viewed the same item twice, I will leave userid=2 as it is.

So I want my data to be like the following:

```
userid itemid
  2       1
  2       2
  2       3
```

Can someone help me?

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2],
                   'itemid':[1,1,3,4, 1,2,3] })
```

Comment: Please post reproducible code that creates that data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to determine the row level duplicates, then perform a `groupby` on 'userid' to determine 'userid' level duplicates, then drop accordingly.

To drop without a threshold:

```
df = df[~df.duplicated(['userid', 'itemid']).groupby(df['userid']).transform('any')]
```

To drop with a threshold, use `keep=False` in `duplicated`, and sum over the Boolean column and compare against your threshold.  For example, with a threshold of 3:

```
df = df[~df.duplicated(['userid', 'itemid'], keep=False).groupby(df['userid']).transform('sum').ge(3)]
```

The resulting output for no threshold:

```
   userid  itemid
4       2       1
5       2       2
6       2       3
```

Comment: What if I want to drop regarding a threshold? That is, what if I want to drop userids with more than 3 duplicates?

Comment: This is a special-case trick for THRESHOLD = 2. For larger THRESHOLD, you need @DYZ's more general code.

Answer (score 7):

## [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration)

Was made for this.  You can pass a function that returns a boolean that determines if the group passed the filter or not.

***`filter` and `value_counts`***
*Most generalizable and intuitive*

```
df.groupby('userid').filter(lambda x: x.itemid.value_counts().max() < 2)
```

***`filter` and `is_unique`***
*special case when looking for `n < 2`*

```
df.groupby('userid').filter(lambda x: x.itemid.is_unique)

   userid  itemid
4       2       1
5       2       2
6       2       3
```

Answer (score 3):

Group the dataframe by users and items:

```
views = df.groupby(['userid','itemid'])['itemid'].count()
#userid  itemid
#1       1         2 <=== The offending row
#        3         1
#        4         1
#2       1         1
#        2         1
#        3         1
#Name: dummy, dtype: int64
```

Find out who saw any item only once:

```
THRESHOLD = 2
viewed = ~(views.unstack() >= THRESHOLD).any(axis=1)
#userid
#1    False
#2     True
#dtype: bool
```

Combine the results and keep the 'good' rows:

```
combined = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(viewed).reset_index())
combined[combined[0]][['userid','itemid']]
#   userid  itemid
#4       2       1
#5       2       2
#6       2       3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# group userid and itemid and get a count
df2 = df.groupby(by=['userid','itemid']).apply(lambda x: len(x)).reset_index()
#Extract rows where the max userid-itemid count is less than 2.
df2 = df2[~df2.userid.isin(df2[df2.ix[:,-1]>1]['userid'])][df.columns]
print(df2)
   itemid  userid
3       1       2
4       2       2
5       3       2
```

If you want to drop at a certain threshold, just set

```
df2.ix[:,-1]>threshold]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether there is a function available in `Pandas` to do this task. However, I tried to make a workaround to deal with your problem.

Here is the full code.

```
import pandas as pd
dictionary = {'userid':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
              'itemid':[1,1,3,4,1,2,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, columns=['userid', 'itemid'])

selected_user = []

for user in df['userid'].drop_duplicates().tolist():

    items = df.loc[df['userid']==user]['itemid'].tolist()
    if len(items) != len(set(items)): continue
    else: selected_user.append(user)

result = df.loc[(df['userid'].isin(selected_user))]
```

This code will result the following outcome.

```
    userid  itemid
4   2       1
5   2       2
6   2       3
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `for user in df['userid'].drop_duplicates().tolist()` can always be replaced by `df.groupby('userid')`